# splitting string in C manually from custom function with pointers as input

Tags: c, string, pointers, null, char

My objective is to read browser cookie data and extract a value based on name of the cookie.

For example, if the cookie data the browser has is something like:

```
ABC=LETTER ; 123=NUMBER ; A12=ALPHANUM
```

and I pass the word ABC to the function, I want to receive the word LETTER as the value. Likewise if I pass A12, I want to receive ALPHANUM.

I'm stuck as to how to scan a string and extract a portion of it to use as output. In the function apr_table_get line and request_rec parameter are both required because this is part of my apache module.

This is how I call the function from the apache handler function in the simplest form (assume r is a pointer to the apache structure):

```
char* cookie=malloc(1000);
get_cookie(r,"ABC\0",cookie);
```

And here's the function:

```
void get_cookie(request_rec *r,const char *name,char*cooky){
    const char* cook=apr_table_get(r->headers_in, "Cookie");
    if (cook){
        char *n=name,*n2=name,*c=cook;int sz=8000;short m=0;
        while (sz-- > 0){
            if (c != ' '){
                if (m==0){if (c==n){*n++;}else{if (c=='='){if (n==0){m=1;}else{m=-1;}}else{m=-1;}}}
if (c==';'){if (m==1){return;}else{m=0;*n=*n2;}}                    

                if (c==';'){m=0;*n=*n2;}
                if (c==0){break;}

            }
            *c++;
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile the code, I get these warnings: "initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type" and "comparison between pointer and integer"

I think It needs fixing, but I'll explain in layman terms how the function must work:

First line receives a pointer to a memory space which contains cookie data.

If there is no data, then function exits.

Next I attempt assign two variables (n and n2) to use as a copy of the cookie name pointer so I can scan through the name. Without prefixing n and n2 with (char*), I get a warning. Same goes with the cookie string pointer.

I also set an integer to 8000 representing the maximum characters the function will scan to prevent program lockup. I also have a small integer for mode (named m in the code).

In the loop the pointer to the cookie string is supposed to be incremented (hence *c++) so that each character is evaluated. I check the raw character on each increment against a set of characters based on mode and spaces are ignored.

If mode is zero, it means reset and search for name. Once name matches (based on the individual characters being equal minus spaces), the mode goes to 1 which means scan value and load up the cooky (output cookie value). If mode is -1, it means there is no match and the loop must find another semicolon to make the mode zero. Once a match is found, the function exits.

In name search mode, the second name pointer(n2) stays the same always, and the 3rd name pointer (n) is incremented so I can grab each individual character in the cookie name up until the first null character or until the character in the cookie data (by scanning c) is an equals sign. Once either of those are hit and no match is found, I make the n pointer equal n2 so that scanning for the name can restart again.

I think what may be throwing me off is improper use of stars and ampersands in my code when referencing pointers, because no matter what I do, nothing is returned.

I want to avoid special string functions (except for the first line in the function) because I want to make execution go as fast as possible.

Can anyone point out what I can fix in my code to make it work?

Comment: I didn't go through your whole code/question but if you want to split your line into strings/tokens why not use `strtok()`?

Comment: I want to achieve the solution that is least processor intensive. If I use special string functions, I might be using more CPU cycles than necessary.

Comment: 8000 is a magic number here. Is cook a C-style string? or does it have any terminator?

Comment: I used 8000 to limit the scanning to 8000 characters. I'm actually unsure if it has a terminator. that is a line I borrowed from somewhere to read in cookie data.

Comment: I'd start by making your code *readable*. Beyond that, almost every use of `c` in this code  is wrong. You're comparing things like `if (c == '=')`, but `c` is `char *`, not `char` or `int`. Nor should it be `char*`l it should be `const char*`. And `n` and `n2` should also be `const char*` as well. You should not be modifying `name`-pointed data as it is declared `const` on-delivery. Forcing such activity through a non-const pointer is plain-wrong. From all appearances you need to review how to use pointers in C, and what `const` *really* means.

Answer (score 0):

> When I compile the code, I get these warnings: "initialization
>   discards qualifiers from pointer target type"

```
        const char * n=name, // ... const was missing
```

> I think what may be throwing me off is improper use of stars and
>   ampersands in my code when referencing pointers

Indeed - obviously the indirection operator `*` has been mistaken for an address operator, or in other words, the pointer variables have been mistaken for C++-like reference variables. Wherever in the loop `n`, `n2` and `c` appear after `*`, the pointer values are meant to be used, so no `*` should be there, and wherever `n`, `n2` and `c` appear without `*`, the `char` object which they point to is meant, so a `*` would be needed.

> nothing is returned.

Still before `return` the copying  of a found cookie value to the `cooky` space is missing. For that, it would be useful to store the value of `c` when the `=` is found.